# Android app closes suddenly with exception Failed looking up window

Tags: android

I am working on a project since past one year. It was working fine but since past two days I noticed a wired behavior. My app closes suddenly without showing any ANR or Crash alert. The app even not found in the stack, it got cleared from there also. In logcat I found this

```
WindowManager: Failed looking up window
                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@edac887 does not exist
                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9100)
                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9091)
                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2296)
                                    at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:193)
                                    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:242)
                                    at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:136)
                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Comment: @MaxV Thanks for your response. No its not a duplicate. Both questions and problem are nonidentical.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: INFO  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138088/android-failed-looking-up-window-with-support-version-27-0-0 is having the same problem.