# Android Failed looking up window with support version 27.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

After the update of `supportVersion` to `27.0.0` ONLY on Android 5.0.2 the app crash with this stacktrace:

```
W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f004691 does not exist
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8426)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8417)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2558)
            at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:186)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2920)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5390)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3223)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Both on the device and on the emulator.

If I put 26.0.2 as supportVersion, the app still works normally as usual.

**UPDATE**

The problem persist with `supportVersion`  `27.0.1`

**UPDATE 2**

Project gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "3.6.0"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        jcenter { url = 'http://dl.bintray.com/swrve-inc/android' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public' }
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/teads/TeadsSDK-android' }
        maven { url 'http://maven.apptimize.com/artifactory/repo' }
        maven { url 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics' }
    }
}

ext {
    //APPLICATION
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.1'
    minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 27

    //LIBRARIES
    timberVersion = '4.6.0'
    guavaVersion = '20.0'
    multidexVersion = '1.0.2'
    supportVersion = '27.0.1'
    constraintVersion = '1.0.2'
    playServiceVersion = '11.4.0'
    commonLangVersion = '3.5'
    jacksonVersion = '2.4.2'
    appsFlyerVersion = '4.7.1'
    facebookAudienceVersion = '4.26.1'
    facebookSkdVersion = '4.26.0'
    facebookAdapterVersion = '4.26.1.0'
    flurryVersion = '6.9.2'
    googleTrackingVersion = '2.2.4'
    crashliticsVersion = '2.6.8'
    swrveVersion = '4.10.1'
    swrveLocationVersion = '1.3'
    pubnativeVersion = '2.0.5'
    localyticsVersion = '4.3.1'
    teadsVersion = '2.4.13'
    oguryPresageVersion = '2.1.21'
    evernoteAndroidJobVersion = '1.1.11'
    apptimizeVersion = '2.13.5'
    comScoreVersion = '5.5.1'
    bottomBarVersion = '2.3.1'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.1.6'
    rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.1'

    //TEST LIBRARIES
    testsVersion = '1.0.1'
    espressoVersion = '3.0.1'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    powermockVersion = '1.6.6'
    robolectricVersion = '3.5'
    assertjVersion = '1.2.0'

    //PUBNATIVE ADAPTERS
    pnFlurryVersion = '6.9.2'
    pnAdmobVersion = '9.6.1'

}
```

App gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.gradle.spotless'

spotless {
    kotlin {
        target "**/*.kt"
        ktlint()
    }
}

def versionMajor = 8
def versionMinor = 8
def versionPatch = 8
def versionBuild = 8 

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    flavorDimensions "std"

    defaultConfig {
        dimension "std"

        applicationId "xxx.yyy.zzz"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode versionMajor * 1000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch * 10 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        //APP VERSION NAME
        buildConfigField "String", "VERSION_NAME_PREFIX", "\"zzzz\""

        //MARKET CONFIG
        buildConfigField "String", "MARKET_NAME", "\"GooglePlay\""
        buildConfigField "String", "MARKET_ENDPOINT", "\"market://details?id=\""
        buildConfigField "String", "MARKET_BACKOFF_ENDPOINT", "\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=\""

        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        ....
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'acb.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
        fatal 'StopShip'

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {

    //CORE LIB
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${rootProject.ext.timberVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:${rootProject.ext.guavaVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:${rootProject.ext.multidexVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:${rootProject.ext.multidexVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${rootProject.ext.constraintVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:${rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${rootProject.ext.commonLangVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${rootProject.ext.jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${rootProject.ext.jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${rootProject.ext.jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rootProject.ext.rxJavaVersion}"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rootProject.ext.rxAndroidVersion}"

    //SDK
    implementation "com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:${rootProject.ext.appsFlyerVersion}@aar"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:${rootProject.ext.facebookSkdVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:${rootProject.ext.facebookAudienceVersion}"
    implementation "com.flurry.android:analytics:${rootProject.ext.flurryVersion}"
    implementation "com.flurry.android:ads:${rootProject.ext.flurryVersion}"
    implementation files("libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-${rootProject.ext.googleTrackingVersion}.jar")
    implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${rootProject.ext.crashliticsVersion}@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }

    //TEADS VIDEO
    implementation("tv.teads.sdk:androidsdk:${rootProject.ext.teadsVersion}:fullRelease@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }

    //OGURY - PRESAGE
    implementation files("libs/presage-lib-${rootProject.ext.oguryPresageVersion}-obfuscated.jar")

    //PUBNATIVE
    implementation "net.pubnative:sdk:${rootProject.ext.pubnativeVersion}"

    //PUBNATIVE - ADAPTERS
    implementation "net.pubnative:sdk.adapter.admob:${rootProject.ext.pnAdmobVersion}"
    implementation "net.pubnative:sdk.adapter.flurry:${rootProject.ext.pnFlurryVersion}"

    //ADMOB - ADAPTERS
    implementation "com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:${rootProject.ext.facebookAdapterVersion}"

    //SWRVE PLOT
    implementation "com.swrve.sdk.android:swrve-google:${rootProject.ext.swrveVersion}"
    implementation(name: "swrve-location-${rootProject.ext.swrveLocationVersion}", ext: "aar")

    //LOCALYTICS
    implementation "com.localytics.android:library:${rootProject.ext.localyticsVersion}"

    //JOB
    implementation "com.evernote:android-job:${rootProject.ext.evernoteAndroidJobVersion}"

    //APPTIMIZE
    implementation "com.apptimize:apptimize-android:${rootProject.ext.apptimizeVersion}"

    //COMSCORE
    implementation "com.comscore:android-analytics:${rootProject.ext.comScoreVersion}"

    //BOTTOM BAR
    implementation "com.roughike:bottom-bar:${rootProject.ext.bottomBarVersion}"

    //TEST
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:${rootProject.ext.testsVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:rules:${rootProject.ext.testsVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:${rootProject.ext.espressoVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:${rootProject.ext.espressoVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:${rootProject.ext.espressoVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    testImplementation "junit:junit:${rootProject.ext.junitVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:${rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:${rootProject.ext.powermockVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${rootProject.ext.powermockVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:${rootProject.ext.powermockVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:${rootProject.ext.powermockVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:${rootProject.ext.robolectricVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:${rootProject.ext.robolectricVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:${rootProject.ext.robolectricVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:${rootProject.ext.assertjVersion}"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What actions cause the crash?

Comment: Nothing .. I launch the application from android studio, startup and crash. Without even seeing the landing page. In the logcat I see the native exception only if I set "no filters", with the default "show only selected application" it shows nothing

Comment: Starting the app is an action. It isn't "nothing".

Comment: The exception you posted here does not appear to have anything to do with your app, though. Can you take a second look at the logcat to see if there is any other errors? Even without the filters, you can search for your app's "application id".

Comment: no, I don't have exception related to my app (with my "application id"), only that one in the question

Comment: When you change to support libs version 27, what build tools version do you use?

Comment: Does it happen on multiple Android 5.0.2 devices or have you tested it on one device running 5.0.2 only?

Comment: @BernardoRocha this happen on each 5.0.2 device, both physical and emulator

Comment: @azizbekian I've try with 26.0.2, 27.0.0 and 27.0.1 without solve the probem

Comment: I suggest you to look into the differences between versions [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/27.0.0/changes.html).

Comment: You need to show your build.gradle file. The error your showing looks like a memory management problem know in android lollipop.

Comment: Please post your gradle config file and maybe some code, It happened to me, but I don't remember the solution..

Comment: `windowForClientLocked`: maybe this happens, when your application is being launched when device is locked.

Comment: @azizbekian nope, the device (or the emulator) is unlocked

Comment: This may be caused by calling a system API that is not available on your target device.

Comment: Did you try upgrading the build and google services plugin version to latest one ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to the `AppCompatActivity` extend for the start activity, When it changed to `Activity` it is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding: `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`

Also set your support version to `27+`

This has helped me in previous instance. Not tried it with `27.0.0` or `27.0.1`

> I know this is not the preferred approach but it can be used as a temporary fix. Wether you want to use it or ignore it, I leave it to you. But let me know if it works.